# Store jquery.ajax POST data in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Here's what I am trying to do.

I have the following script which will POST data from index.php on the same page(index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadabc(){
            var optionValue = jQuery("select[name='citycountrystores']").val();     
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: ({result: optionValue}),
                        success: function(response){
                            jQuery("#cityAjax").html(response);
                            jQuery("#cityAjax").show();
                        }
                    });
```

I want to access the POST data in php.
The php statements are written in the same javascript.
I need to access $_POST['result'] in a php if statement like:

```
<?php
if($check==$_POST['result'])
{
code....
.........
    }
    ?>
}//Function loadabc end
    </script>
```

This is my select box

```
<select id="citycountrystores" name="citycountrystores" onchange="loadabc();">
  <option value="76">City1</option>
  <option value="77">City2</option>
  <option value="78">City3</option>
</select>
```

I can see the POST value(76 or 77 or 78) in the console. But i would like to know how to store it in a php variable for immediate access.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this, or any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediate access"? You want to use it where?

Comment: I mean to say that i am posting on the same page and i have my php statements in the same script so i need to access the value there itself.

Comment: Aaaa ... I understood, sorry :)

Comment: I'm calling loadabc() onchange event of select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access same page from `AJAX` you need to end your script before it prints the rest of the page out, first lines in code should be:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['result']) &&  ($_POST['result'] != '')){
            if($_POST['result'] == 77){
                echo "My selected code: ".$_POST['result'];
            } else {
                echo "something else";
            }
            die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but i actually had the javascript called on selectbox onchange event... At that time I was able to see the POSTed result. But after changing it to jQuery("").onchange(function()) i don't get the POST result

Comment: I've added it.. However it didn't make any difference
But in response in my function loadabc() I get "My selected code: 77".
The code in the if statement still doesn't execute

Comment: Yes, but how can i use it in the php if statement

Comment: what do you mean? how can you use it?

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'll try it out

Comment: Well I've tried it, but it did'nt work.
The code doesn't check the condition.
The statement you've provided doesn't show up on the page but in Response I can see it.

Comment: You can only see it on the page with AJAX (your response), you cannot modify with PHP a rendered HTML page. That's why AJAX was made.

Comment: Then how can i modify a rendered HTML page? Please let me know. I'm stuck up with this since the past few days.

Comment: exactly the code you mentioned `jQuery("#cityAjax").html(response);`

Comment: I'm a little new to jQuery Ajax. Can you please elaborate on that.
I just need to check the value in the php statement.
Can you please show me a way.

Comment: I'm still unable to output the echo in the if condition on the page, even with those changes

Answer (score 0):

Declare you cities in a php array like this

```
$cities = array(
    76 => "City 1",
    77 => "City 2",
    78 => "City 3",
);
```

Then to use these values in the option you can do something like this

```
<select id="citycountrystores" name="citycountrystores">
    <?php foreach($cities as $value => $label) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$value}\">{$label}</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
```

you can then also use that array to see what value was submitted by looking the array at the posted value index.

```
$submittedCity = $cities[$_POST['result']];
```

Answer (score 0):

ummm not sure what you mean but if you're trying to utilize the ajax posted data as a php variable in the same page then I believe you could try utilizing the jquery load method to refresh the required DOM node. 
Since I'm not sure if I understood your question so I'm not going into much details. Lemme know if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mihai's suggestion i think you need to to modify the jquery code which get the selectbox value to

```
var optionValue = jQuery("#citycountrystores").val();
```